# Intellij Idea: Scala plugin: No compile library set for module

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Wanted to start using intellij idea for my scala project and stumbled upon this link - http://theyougen.blogspot.in/2010/01/how-to-setup-maven-scala-project-with.html

Followed the steps, created a new Scala Project (without sbt), Create a new Scala Class, and copied the HelloWorld code from Scala tutorial - http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/166.html

Went to *Build* > *Make Project* and got following error -

> No compiler library set for module.

Went to *File* > *Project Structure*. On the left side, clicked on *facets*, and noticed that Under **Compiler** ***Compiler Library*** was set to *none*. And there is no other option available in the drop down.

How to solve this?

PS: Googled a lot, could not find any clue on how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on **MAC**

1. Download scala from http://www.scala-lang.org/download/
2. Extract it to some-location/scala
3. In Intellij Idea go to File, Project Structure and select Global Libraries.
4. Click on + button
5. Select Java
6. Give the path to some-location/scala/lib
7. Click ok
8. Apply and OK.
9. Go to File, Project Structure, facets. You will see a new Scala library in drop-down.

Comment: Also, on Mac you can use Homebrew: brew install scala

Comment: This solution worked for me, too. Note that if you've used HomeBrew to install scala, then the library will likely be located at a path like /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.4/libexec/lib and you need to specify that on the 6th step given in the answer.